# Consuming signalr with angular 7 with proxy url

Tags: angular, signalr

I want to consume SignalR with AngularJs with angulat cli proxy URL. Please guide me how can I achieve this. It is working fine with below URL but when I replace the URL according to proxy URL it is not working.

```
signalRUrl = "https://localhost:5500/logs/";
private hubConnection!: signalR.HubConnection;
`constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }` 
`public startConnection = () => {`
   `this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(this.signalRUrl).build();`
  ` this.hubConnection.start()`
   `.then(() => alert('Connection started'))`
  `.catch(err => alert('Error while starting connection: ' + err))}`
```